# how i can put the shadow inset from one side

Tags: html, css

i want the shadow to appear in one side (Top) with css only,

i have tried many solutions but always there is a shadow in all sides

this is my try

```css
.box-container{
  width:100%;
  height: 80px;
  padding:10px 10%;
  background-color: #f00;
}
.box-inner{
  width:80%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #ff0;
  box-shadow: inset 0 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="box-container">
<div class="box-inner"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see a issue here? The box shadow is appearing on the top only.

Comment: @RasmusGlenvig, fox in the result,  there is a shadow in other sides too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this:

```css
.box-container{
  width:100%;
  height: 80px;
  padding:10px 10%;
  background-color: #f00;
}
.box-inner{
  width:80%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #ff0;
  box-shadow: inset 0 20px 20px -20px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
```

```html
<div class="box-container">
<div class="box-inner"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please do try this `box-shadow: inset 0 7px 9px -7px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);` for only top

Think this will help you...

Answer (score 1):

try to use this

```css
.box-container{
  width:100%;
  height: 80px;
  padding:10px 10%;
  background-color: #f00;
}
.box-inner{
  width:80%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #ff0;
  -moz-box-shadow:    inset  0  8px 8px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset  0  8px 8px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  box-shadow:        inset  0  8px 8px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
```

```html
<div class="box-container">
<div class="box-inner"></div>
</div>
```

Have a look at  http://www.css3.info/preview/box-shadow/  for more information about box-shadow.

Hope this was what you were looking for!